# MongoDB Model not working in NextJS API but working from frontend

Tags: mongoose, next.js, server-action

I am getting an error if I call the server action that calls the MongoDB model from API but works perfectly from the front end. here is the error. Anything I am doing wrong?

````
> database/question.model.ts (49:0) @ <unknown>
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Question')
> 47 | });
> 48 |
> 49 | const Question = models.Question || model("Question", QuestionSchema);
> 50 |
> 51 | export default Question;
> 52 |
> Compiling /_error ...
> Compiled /_error ```
>
````

here is the model code.

```
import { Schema, models, model, Document } from "mongoose";

export interface IQuestion extends Document {
  quetions: string;
  author: Schema.Types.ObjectId[];
  answers: string;
}

const QuestionSchema = new Schema({
  questions: { type: String, required: true },
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  answers: { type: String, required: false },
});

const Question = models.Question || model("Question", QuestionSchema);

export default Question;
```

server action

```
export async function getQuestionsCount(params: GetCountByAuthorParams) {
  try {
    connectToDatabase();

    const { author } = params;

    console.log("Author", author);

    const query: FilterQuery<typeof Question> = {
      author,
    };

    const totalQuestions = await Question.countDocuments(query);
    return totalQuestions;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Calling the server action from the front end:

```
      author: userIdRef.current!,
    };

    const total = await getQuestionsCount(params);
    console.log("Total Count", total);
```

working

Calling from API/route.ts

const params: GetCountByAuthorParams = {
author: authorID!,
};

```
const total = await getQuestionsCount(params);
console.log("Total Count", total);
```

Not working.

Answer (score 0):

I can able to call the server actions from route.ts after I removed the NextJS edge code or change to nodejs

```
export const runtime = 'nodejs' (default) | 'edge'
```